# Itemscontrol behave like a wizard

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a itemscontrol with few TextBoxes and TextBlocks.

I want my xaml to display only the first item and on click of a button eg 'Next' button, the second item should be display. A good example is a wizard but obviously my controls on each page will remain the same. Is it at all possible? Any clues/ hints how? Please help.

Comment: Your question is very unspecific i will try to answer i too though.

Comment: @Vitor Canova The only idea I have is to have a itemsource with only one item at a time but I will try Dragosh Stoica's approach in answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An aproach is to create boolean properties for **visibility**, and with the help of a converter make visibile or invisible some items
2. Use **Navigation**, make separate pages and navigate through them with a "Next" button.
3. Use a **content presenter** in order to load what controls you want

Answer (score 0):

You create another Parent Control which Childs you switch on each button click.

For example you have an Imagebox and on each button click you take the next image from a list and load it into that Imagebox.